# Opensource Nuget packages to open and read Excel files in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Any Opensource Nuget packages available to open and read Excel files in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages

Answer (score 2):

you can try EPPlus or ClosedXML nuget packages. you can read/write/save

Answer (score 0):

[EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) A library to manage Excel spreadsheets, using OOXML.